# How do browsers pass applets the parameters?

Tags: java, applet, browser

So as the title says, I want to know how the applet -> param tag works. For example, you can do:

```
<applet id="applet" code="MyApplet.class" width=100 height=100>
    <param name="someParam" value="someValue">
    <param name="someParam2" value="someValue2">
</applet>
```

And somehow, the browser invokes the JVM and loads this applet. Next it passes the parameters to the applet. I want to know how it gives the applet the parameters. Applets do not have a "setParameter" function.

So how does the browser give the "params" to the applet? I tried creating an `AppletStub` that contains a `HashMap` and setting the applet's applet stub and that works just fine.

I doubt browsers do that though. Any ideas how it passes the HTML param to the applet?